# Elasticsearch2.2.0 no aws cloud plugin

Tags: configuration, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-stack, amazon-ec2

I have an instance running **Elasticsearch-1.4.4** and also installed **AWS Cloud Plugin 2.4.2** and all is working on an ELK Stack.

I want to now try **Elasticsearch 2.2.0** but there doesn't seem to be **AWS Cloud Plugin** for that version? 
[on the github page](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws)

Can anyone help me solve this?

I would like to upgrade my ELK Stack to all the latest but just want to try get it running on an EC2 instance first.

Thanks in advance

G

Answer (score 0):

The Readme section mentions that the project has now moved to the elasticsearch repository (from elasticsearch 2.0.0). Hence, if you are using a higher version, it will be present within the elasticsearch repo. Look inside the plugins directory.

Comment: Yes I did see that and followed the steps for installing and I can even get the status response 200 when I hit url:9200.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many times , and I figured out

sudo bin/plugin install cloud-aws , give it a try .

Comment: Yes did try and when it was installing it said installing ..../aescloud/2.2.0.zip which is even older? I will have another look and post stack trace.